# Ctrl + Dot not showing using intellisense menu

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have Visual Studio 2015 Community edition. When I add type Class name that needs a reference to another namespace in solution, to add the using reference I normally press Ctrl + . and the menu shows available/related options but I cannot see it anymore not even any option to select by mouse. I have attached the error image.

Already tried Install-Package Mi[image]crosoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform

Comment: Did you try installing this.... Install-Package Microsoft.CodeAnalysis

Comment: Install [VS 2015 Update 3](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs). It helped me.